# VerneMQ plugin force disconnect client

Tags: plugins, erlang, mqtt

I'm developing a VerneMQ plugin for jwt authentication in which I need to disconnect a client inside the auth_on_publish plugin if it's jwt token is expired.

Is it possible to close a connection inside a plugin hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on the VerneMQ slack channel, provided by the VerneMQ developer himself:

> All the `auth_on_x` hooks are executed in the MQTT session process, so you can send it a `disconnect` message like this: `self() ! disconnect`, and the client will be disconnected.

So, inside the auth_on_publish plugin, when my authentication expires, I just run `self() ! disconnect` and the client is disconnected as desired.

Note, however, that this is using internals of VerneMQ and is not guaranteed to work forever. Currently no 'official' API exists for this feature.